# PHP How to use class instance inside method

Tags: php, class

How can I use class instance inside independent method?
I some file have:

```
global $l;
$l = new l('bg');
include('second.php');
```

In second.php I have:

```
function a() {
    print_r($l);
}
```

$l is coming like NULL;

class l declaration:

```
class l {
    var $lang = array();
    function l($lang) {
    }
    function g($string) {
    }
}
```

My question - how can I use $l instance inside of my function a.
Thanks.

Comment: `$l` is not in scope, `global $l` would work, but you could also pass it to the function as a parameter (better).

Comment: why passing as parameter is better solution? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In function `a` `$l` is not defined.

Either you pass it in as a parameter or you use `global`.

```
function a($l) {
    print_r($l);
}
```

`global` is **not** like `var`. It does **not** define a variable to be used as a global. Instead, global allows you to pull variables from the global scope, like:

```
$l = new l();
function a() {
    global $l;
    print_r($l);
}
```

---

I should also add that the use of `global` is heavily frowned upon, it breaks dependency expectations. This means that if you look at your function `a` you can't see that it *needs* `$l`. If it's a parameter then you know it needs `$l`.

Comment: Absolutely fabulous! Thank you.